# setting template file using template_preproccess_page not working

Tags: theming, 6

I have a list of pages with url

```
?q=value/abc/1
?q=value/abc/2
?q=value/abc/3
?q=value/abc/4
```

for which i require a specific template.I have written a `template_preprocess_page` function,but it does not call the required `tpl` file.But if i set the test variable as 
`$test = array("value/abc/1");` 
the template file is being used.Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong..??

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$var){  
 $test = array("value/abc/%"); 
        if(in_array($_GET['q'], $test)){
            $var['template_file'] = 'testing';
        }
}
```

Comment: You've tagged this as Drupal 6 _and_ 7...which are you actually using? And I'd be interested to know where you've seen an example that uses `template_file` I've never seen that used before

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/223440,

Comment: So I can guess you're using Drupal 6 from that? Read the examples again, you have typos and small errors in your code that don't match up with what you've tried to copy

Comment: tanx for joinin in @Clive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming D6 then, in template.php:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables){  
 if (strpos($_GET['q'], 'value/abc') === 0) {
   $variables['template_file'] = 'testing';
 }
}
```

Clear theme registry, or all caches at `admin > config > performance` to apply.

More info:

> There are two special variables that these hooks can set:
>   'template_file' and 'template_files'. These will be merged together to
>   form a list of 'suggested' alternate template files to use, in reverse
>   order of priority. template_file will always be a higher priority than
>   items in template_files. theme() will then look for these files, one
>   at a time, and use the first one that exists.
>   https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/6

Comment: That's not right. Have a look at the docs the OP linked to, you have the same typo and error that I mentioned in the comments (although you did fix up the path-test nicely)

Comment: Hi Clive, You can use `template_file` to add a single suggestion, rather than an array in `template_files`. ( more info added on that ) I adjusted the function name from template_preprocess_page. Can you be more specific if other error(s) there?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realise that, my bad :) those are the only 2 'errors' I was talking about, I was trying to encourage the OP to double check his code against the examples as it didn't match up. Didn't realise it didn't _need_ to!

Comment: Heh, no worries, `template_file` is a curious feature, D7 has a similar feature in `theme_hook_suggestion` vs `theme_hook_suggestions` Cheers.

Comment: tanx for the info @DavidThomas.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to set up five content-type templates. You can read more about this [here](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) and in this [tutorial](http://highrockmedia.com/blog/creating-custom-content-type-page-templates-drupal-php). Essentially if you wish to use a template, you need to create a content-type for it. Then you can use your content-type machine name (let's say your content type's machine name is "foo" then your template PHP file will be titled "page--foo.tpl.php"

You have to then add this to the top of your template.php in your main theme:

```
function YourTheme_process_page(&$variables) {
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $variables['node']->type;
}
```

Then you can add a content page for each content type and give it the path you need (ie value/abc/1 or value/abc/2 etc).

If the processing you do with your URL value is minimal, then you can also just retrieve the value through the PHP $_GET function and then use it in your PHP processing as needed (after sanitizing the variable of course).

Comment: I think we're leaning towards the OP using Drupal 6 (although for some reason he seems reluctant to share that information). This is a good answer for D7 but won't work for D6